# OpenGLHow to fit a texture to a curved plane with GL_CLAMP

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to fit a texture on a curved plane made from some triangles  with `GL_CLAMP`, because `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE` is not available in my OpenGL version, but the texture (512 x 512 pixels) appears so small when render:

```
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP); // If the u,v coordinates overflow the range 0,1 the image is repeated
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR); // The magnification function ("linear" produces better results)
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR); //The minifying function

glTexGeni(GL_S, GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE,  GL_OBJECT_LINEAR);
glTexGeni(GL_T, GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE, GL_OBJECT_LINEAR); 
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_T);
```

[image]

I load the texture like this:

```
glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECR );    
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 4, infoheader.biWidth, infoheader.biHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, l_texture);
gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 4, infoheader.biWidth, infoheader.biHeight, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, l_texture);
```

Comment: It's not clear to me from this image what the problem is. Can you show us what the input texture and UV unwrap for the mesh look like, and give us an idea of what should be different in this image when it's working the way you want it to?

Comment: The texture is a face that fills a BMP of size 512x512. The mesh is created by code from a Bezier curve with normals. The UVs are  auto generated from the code above. I want the texture to wrap the whole plane mesh with one repeat. If I put GL_REPEAT instead of GL_CLAMP it fills the entire mesh but repeating the texture many times. Since the mesh are many triangles, is it posible repaeat only once with GL_CLAMP?. Notice that i can generated UV's by code, but it not easy when the mesh twits like this plane, so I woud like to do that job with OPENGL automatic GL_CLAMP